# MySQL query, subquery in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

im using codeigniter as my framework, but i'm not using active records, im having trouble executing this query, it gives me a Error Number 1064

essentialy, im trying to insert a bunch of data to a table, but querying some id numbers from other tables

```
$titulo = $datos['titulo'];
    $tipo   =   $datos['tipo'];
    $autor  =   $datos['autor'];
    $autor2 =   $datos['autor2'];
    $editorial =    $datos['editorial'];
    $ano        =   $datos['ano'];
    $paginas    =   $datos['paginas'];
    $descripcion =  $datos['descripcion'];
    $image_path =   'hola';
    $genero     =   $datos['genero'];
    $genero2    =   $datos['genero2'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO productos (titulo, autor_id, autor2_id, editorial_id, ano, paginas, genero_id,
             genero2_id, tipo, descripcion, image_path)
             SELECT ? AS titulo,
             id FROM autores WHERE nombre_autor=?,
             id FROM autores WHERE nombre_autor=?,
             id FROM editoriales WHERE nombre_editorial=?,
             ? as ano, 
             ? as paginas,
             id FROM generos WHERE nombre_genero=?,
             id FROM generos WHERE nombre_genero=?,
             ? as tipo,
             ? as descripcion,
             ? as image_path";

    if($this->db->query($sql, array($titulo, $autor, $autor2, $editorial, $ano, $paginas, $genero, $genero2, $tipo, $descripcion, $image_path))){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

can someone help me with this query?

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

A select statement can only have one FROM clause.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Look into using JOIN

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect query since I do not know the design of your database, but it should steer you in the right direction as far as the syntax goes.

```
INSERT INTO productos (titulo, autor_id, autor2_id, editorial_id, ano, paginas, genero_id,
         genero2_id, tipo, descripcion, image_path)
SELECT a.titulo, b.id, b.id2, c.id, a.ano, a.paginas, d.id, d.id2, a.tipo, a.description, a.image_path
FROM table_1 a
JOIN table_2 b ON a.autor_id = b.id
JOIN table_3 c ON a.editorial_id = c.id
JOIN table_4 d ON a.genero_id = d.id
WHERE a.id = 25
```

Essentially this will join all of the data you need into one table before you add into "productos". This is the proper way to do what you need with SQL. Of course, this also depends on the relationships between the tables--in this example I assumed that you had foreign keys in table_1 that referred to data in other tables.

You will then be able to execute this query based on whatever parameters you want/need--just refer to those in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks, let me check it out

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?